# Creating variations of a property heavy class

Tags: c#, design

What kind of pattern or design can prevent the creation of a class packed with properties that aren't always used?

Example

```
class Car{
   public string type;
   public string name;
   public DateTime manufactured;
   public int model;
   public Color color;
   public int VIN;
   // ..and on
}

public Car(string name, Color color){
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
}
```

Sometimes you want to make a Car with just some info, like the make and model, but you always want it to have a few defaults. How do you avoid 20 children classes or constructor overloads in this case?

Comment: In addition to the answers below (all of which are valid since this question is kinda broad), you may be interested in the Builder pattern: Car myCar = new CarBuilder().setMake(...).setModel(...).build();

Comment: What are you using this class for in the first place?

Comment: I would highlight @Ixrec's comment: the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is exactly aimed at solving this problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid multiple constructor overloads by using one constructor with named, optional arguments.

```
public Car(string name, Color color, string type="sedan", string model = "Taurus")
```

...which you can call thusly:

```
var car = new Car("Ford", Color.Red)
```

`type` and `model` are optional; it will set `type` to "sedan`and`model` to "Taurus" automatically, unless you override them in the parameter list.

**Further Reading**
[Named and Optional Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: `int model = "Taurus"`? Also you are passing `"Red"` as a `Color`. +1 for the solution but the example is problematic. `model` would probably not be a property with a default value, as it greatly depends on the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

An often overlooked option in this case is seperating the interface from the implementation. Of course if you can live with them being public properties, by all means. If that is not an option consider making Car a private class of the class that would do the instantiation and then make an interface for the getters only like this.

```
interface ICar
{
    int Foo{get;}
    string Bar{get;}
}

class SomeService
{
    private class MyCar : ICar
    {
        int Foo{get;set;}
        string Bar{get;set;}
    }
    public ICar MakeCar()
    {
        return new MyCar{/*todo*/}
    }
}
```

Now the caller have complete control while you still provide encapsulation to the consumers.

Answer (score 2):

The way to avoid having to have a zillion overloads in the constructor is to assign to your properties (they should be properties, BTW, not fields,) outside of the constructor.

> Sometimes you want to make a Car with just some info, like the make and model, but you always want it to have a few defaults.

Then do exactly that: have the constructor require the required info, and then set the rest of the properties to defaults.  Then you can call the constructor with extra-property syntax if you want to override those defaults:

```
var myCar = new Car("Ford", "Taurus") {Color = ModelColors.Blue, VIN = myVIN};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just make them public properties. Since they are optional, the caller should be able to assign a value to them, or set them to null if they already have a value. That would make it easier for callers to assign values as needed. Sometimes the callers have certain code flows which allows assigning properties at that point much more convenient. Without making them properties, that cannot be supported.

If you go with that pattern, you could make them auto-properties, and each method can validate the properties it requires and throw appropriate exceptions. This gets away with doing a lot of validations with different combinations in the constructor (regardless of whether you take them as optional parameters in the constructor or not).

As for the callers, they can call the constructor with required properties and use initializers for assigning values to auto-properties, e.g.

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Manufactured { get; set; }
    public int Model { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public int Vin { get; set; }
    public Car (string name, DateTime manufactured)
    { ... } // required properties

    public Register()
    {
        if (Vin == 0) { throw new SomeException(); }
        // Code to register here
    }
}
```

And consuming code:

```
public void Method()
{
    Car myCar = new Car("myCar", DateTime.Now())
    {
        Model = 5 // Every caller may not need to assign it.
    };

    if (someCondition) { myCar.Color = Color.Red; }
    MethodA(car);
    car.Register();
}

private void MethodA(Car car)
{
    if (someCheck || methodCall())
    { car.Vin = 888; }
}
```

Note that this saves the latter code from having to use other variables to return some value from a child method, which can directly operate on car and set the property. Keeping design discussion aside, in more involved code, I have had to change my classes to support this pattern (i.e. auto-properties) as opposed to hard checks in constructors.

There can definitely be some exceptions to this pattern, but this seems to be a widely used pattern and you can find many .NET framework class libraries that support this. I use this by default unless there is a reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze what properties work closly together and make a class of each of these groups. They may group around the natural systems like electrical, engine, transmission; and notional groupings like performance, Identity, options.

As you work these groups look for redundant properties. These individual properties could be DRYed up to become a class that is used to minimally initialize any car. Other car aspect classes will have a reference to this as needed.

Given a minimally initialized car you can lazy load other car aspect objects as needed.

While all the above looks like just composition, thorough requirements and design analysis will yield complementary inheritance, composition, constructor overloads, and patterns like factory, builder, or even visitor to allow flexible construction and ensure object integrity.

Client code should not set individual car aspect-object properties. The client would need to know everything about the internal functionality of the car class in order to do it right. So besides a factory for initialization you might have builder classes that encapsulate/control injection of additional car aspect objects, the constructor parameters ensuring the car object will be in a valid state.

The above builder classes and factory may work by broad vehicle classifications like sports car, truck, luxury sedan, flying car, etc.

Finally, these car aspect classes should not be merely stupid DTO-type things - all state and no function. I find that even minimal things like overriding ToString, Equals, maybe implement IComparable, makes composition better and the levels of composition tend to stay simpler.